# Count the number of lists that starts with the same item in a list

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7, count

So I have a list like:

```
result = [["1", "1", "a", 8.2],["1", "2", "c", 6.2],["2", "1", "a", 8.2]]
```

I want a function that returns the count of number of lists that starts `(index[0])` with variable `"n"`. So, if `n = '1'` I in this case get 2, if `n = '2'` `I get 1`.

Edit: I've tried a few things like this, but can't get anything to work.

```
def Count(list,n):
result = []
value = 0
for i in list:
    if str(i[0]) == n:
        value = value + 1
        sum.append[value]
return len(sum)

print Count(result,1)
```

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: There are no sublists there that start with `1`, unless you meant `'1'`.

Comment: Do all sublists have the same length?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've added one thing I tried.

Comment: *"can't get anything to work"* - be more specific. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? SO is not here to do your job/homework for you.

Comment: @FeatherMarauder Ok, I added a solution below based on this information and also revised your code. Please let me know if you have questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the list have the same length, you can do the following:

```
import itertools

result = [["1", "1", "a", 8.2],["1", "2", "c", 6.2],["2", "1", "a", 8.2]]

res=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(result))

res[0::4].count('1')
# prints 2
res[0::4].count('2')
#prints 1
```

First, you flatten the list of lists using `itertools.chain` (which is very efficient if you have huge lists; otherwise a simple list comprehension might be faster), then you get the first element of each of the sublists and count how often a certain string is present.

The corrected function you wrote:

```
result = [["1", "1", "a", 8.2],["1", "2", "c", 6.2],["2", "1", "a", 8.2]]

def Count(myList,n):

    value = 0
    for i in myList:
        if i[0] == str(n):
            value = value + 1               

    return value

print Count(result,2)
```

Do not use the word `list` as a parameter/variable name. Since you actually pass a number, you have to convert `n` to a string (the element in your sublist is already a string); the line with `sum.append` is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [["1", "1", "a", 8.2],["1", "2", "c", 6.2],["2", "1", "a", 8.2]]
lst2 = [item[0] for item in result]
lst2.count("1")
```

---

```
result = [["1", "1", "a", 8.2],["1", "2", "c", 6.2],["2", "1", "a", 8.2]]

def Count(myList,n):
    lst2 = [item[0] for item in myList]
    return lst2.count(str(n))

print Count(result,1) #prints 2
print Count(result,2) #prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest answer for you. Your teacher will never believe you wrote it though, sorry.

```
def f(n, lists):
    return len(filter(lambda l: l[0] == n, lists))
```